# Tableau expression in qlik sense

Tags: tableau-api, qliksense

I am using this expression in **Tableau** and am looking to convert it to QlikSense.

```
{ fixed [Customer Number]: if COUNTD([Order Number])>25 then 'Frequent Shoppers' Else 'Non-Frequent Shoppers' END}
```

The expression counts when the order number is greater than 25 for each customer number.

Customer number and order number are the two separate columns in the table XYZ. What would be the expression for dimension in **QlikSense**

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how your data is structured, in your question you refer to them as columns in the same table but your query looks like it is performing a distinct count suggestive that there is a one to many relationship.

A direct translation of your query is as below

```
if(count(distinct [Order Number])>25,'Frequent Shoppers','Non-Frequent Shoppers')
```

Comment: I tried this, but it is  not counting based on Customer number.

Comment: @DEEPAKKM where are you trying to implement it? on a chart or in a script? if in a chart, just add the customer id as another dimension - if it's in the script you will need to post more info